# A badly convergent p-adic series from one of the Schikhof's excercises

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, convergence-divergence, p-adic-number-theory

W. H. Schikhof in his book on Ultrametric calculus suggests to solve the following problem:

> Exercise 23.J (van Hamme) Use the ideas of the previous excercise to show that in $\mathbb Q_p$ ($p \neq 2$):
>   $$S_p := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2 (n+1)!}{4^n+1} = -1.$$

The previous excercise simply states that in every $\mathbb Q_p$ we have $\sum_{n \ge 0} n \cdot n! = -1$. The series clearly converges at least in $\mathbb Q_3$, where $|4^n + 1|_3 = 1$ regardless of $n$ and $|(n+1)!|_3$ tends to zero, and we can invoke the famous ultrametric theorem concerning convergence of series (the necessary convergence condition is sufficient too).

However investigating the series $S_3$ in Pari-GP reveals that it doesn't really gets closer to $-1$, as
$$1 + S_3 = 2 + 3 + 2\cdot 3^3 + 3^4 + 3^5 + 3^7 + 2 \cdot 3^{10} + \ldots $$

In that case I have to ask what is the proper limit of $S_p$ and where can I find the original paper written by van Hamme where he implicitly derives the value of $S_p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was indeed very minor. I am almost sure that after correction the exercise shall state

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2(n+1)!}{4^{n+1}} = -4.
$$

For a proof see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719750/where-do-these-p-adic-identities-come-from/1720668#1720668).
The series does not converge in $\mathbb Q_2$ because the necessary condition is not fulfilled: if we take $n = 2k +1$ then

$$
\begin{align}
v_2 \left(\frac{n^2 (n+1)!}{2^{2n + 2}}\right) & \le 2v_2(n) (n+1) - (2n + 2)\\
& = 0,
\end{align}
$$
so infinitely often the $n$-th summand has $2$-adic norm equal to $1$ (or something larger).