# Prove that for any prime $p$ we have $|\sum_{n\ge 1} n^2(n+1)!|_p=2$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

This is a strange question and I don't know how to deal with this infinite series in p-adic evaluation. Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: how is $|\sum_{n \ge 1} n^2(n+1)!|_p$ defined? If you don't know how it's defined, your question should be "how is it defined" rather than asking someone to solve your problem and merely saying "I don't know how to deal with this"

Comment: I tried to sum until n=7. The result is 2177282_10 = 1024133112_5. This thing doesn't converge to ....00002.

Comment: Do you have a link to the source of the task?

Comment: I summed 1*2+4*6+9*24+25*120....

Comment: I tried to treat those as 2+12!+36!+... That doesn't work as well

Comment: Oh, I see, the convergence is kinda slow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do these p-adic identities come from?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719750/where-do-these-p-adic-identities-come-from)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your question should be:

> Show that for any prime $p$,  $|\sum_{n=1}^N n^2(n+1)!-2|_p\to 0$ where $|\cdot |_p$ is the [$p$-adic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order).

Since $n^2(n+1)!=(n-1)(n+2)!-(n-2)(n+1)!$, it follows that
$$a_N:=\sum_{n=1}^Nn^2(n+1)!=\sum_{n=1}^N((n-1)(n+2)!-(n-2)(n+1)!)=(N-1)(N+2)!+2.$$
Hence $a_N-2=(N-1)(N+2)!$ converges $p$-adically to $0$, i. e. $a_N$ converges $p$-adically to $2$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, I edited my answer with a possible interpretation of the question.